# Timeranges overlapping algorithm in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, datetime

I have a list of different ids, start dates and end dates,
let's say :

```
[
(5, d.datetime(2010, 9, 19, 0, 0, 0),    d.datetime(2010, 9, 19, 0, 5, 10)),
(6, d.datetime(2010, 9, 19, 0, 0, 0),    d.datetime(2010, 9, 19, 12, 59, 59)),
(4, d.datetime(2010, 9, 19, 10, 30, 17), d.datetime(2010, 9, 19, 20, 20, 59)),
(6, d.datetime(2010, 9, 19, 14, 12, 0),  d.datetime(2010, 9, 19, 23, 59, 59)),
(5, d.datetime(2010, 9, 19, 17, 0, 22),  d.datetime(2010, 9, 19, 19, 14, 20))
]
```

I need somehow to find overlapping timerange and prepare new list with properly ids which were under coverage at the specific timerange, for example for list above result should be :

```
[
('5,6',   d.datetime(2010, 9, 19, 0, 0, 0),    d.datetime(2010, 9, 19, 0, 5, 10),
('6',     d.datetime(2010, 9, 19, 0, 5, 10),   d.datetime(2010, 9, 19, 10, 30, 17),
('4,6',   d.datetime(2010, 9, 19, 10, 30, 17), d.datetime(2010, 9, 19, 12, 59, 59),
('4',     d.datetime(2010, 9, 19, 12, 59, 59), d.datetime(2010, 9, 19, 14, 12, 0),
('4,6',   d.datetime(2010, 9, 19, 14, 12, 0),  d.datetime(2010, 9, 19, 17, 0, 22),
('4,5,6', d.datetime(2010, 9, 19, 17, 0, 22),  d.datetime(2010, 9, 19, 19, 14, 20),
('4,6',   d.datetime(2010, 9, 19, 19, 14, 20), d.datetime(2010, 9, 19, 20, 20, 59),
('6',     d.datetime(2010, 9, 19, 20, 20, 59), d.datetime(2010, 9, 19, 23, 59, 59)
]
```

Visual concept:

[image]

Actually for now I've solution like this: I'm getting minimal and maximum dates of the whole range, then start iterate from min_date to max_date each 1 second, when in particular second we match some of intervals from target list, I save matched ids as dictionary key and append time from iterator to list as value, then save it to parent list, then next and next. At final I go over all dicts in parent list and get ids as keys and first, last date in value list as range that I need to find.
But this solution works very slow when I count ranges in month. Because it's takes too much time iterate 1 month in seconds.

Here is code:

```
    def delta(start, end, delta):
        cur = start
        while cur < end:
            yield cur
            cur += delta

    final_ranges = []
    last_result = None
    i = -1
    for checker_date in delta(
            sorted_ranges_by_start[0]['start'],
            sorted_ranges_by_end[-1]['end'],
            relativedelta(seconds=1)):

        aggregator = []
        for rng in ranges:
            if rng['start'] <= checker_date <= rng['end']:
                aggregator.append(str(rng['id']))

        if len(aggregator) > 0:
            ids = ','.join(set(aggregator))
            if last_result != ids:
                final_ranges.append({})
                last_result = ids
                i += 1

            if ids not in final_ranges[i]:
                final_ranges[i][ids] = []

            final_ranges[i][ids].append(checker_date)
```

But as I said it's working very slow in big ranges.

In this way please help me find algorithm that can do it without iteration through month or maybe advice any way to improve iteration speed ( not sure, maybe try to write this part on C and then embed to Python )

Thanks.

Comment: shouldn't it be as simple as start_time_a > end_time_b or start_time_b < end_time_a?

Comment: @KlausD. I've add some code, how it working now

Comment: @Ajurna not sure that I get your idea, can you write full answer if your algorithm resolve my sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've make it work with the code below.

Basic explanation is to first detect cut points between provided periods, that is, everytime a period starts on ends. Second, iterate between cutpoints only, not periods, and check if they overlap with any to see if they are active between those cut points. Accumulate active periods.

Process time depends on the number of cutpoints and periods, and not on elapsed time.

```
from datetime import datetime
from sortedcontainers import SortedSet

periods = [
    (5, datetime(2010, 9, 19, 0, 0, 0),    datetime(2010, 9, 19, 0, 5, 10)),
    (6, datetime(2010, 9, 19, 0, 0, 0),    datetime(2010, 9, 19, 12, 59, 59)),
    (4, datetime(2010, 9, 19, 10, 30, 17), datetime(2010, 9, 19, 20, 20, 59)),
    (6, datetime(2010, 9, 19, 14, 12, 0),  datetime(2010, 9, 19, 23, 59, 59)),
    (5, datetime(2010, 9, 19, 17, 0, 22),  datetime(2010, 9, 19, 19, 14, 20))
]

cutpoints = SortedSet()

for period in periods:
    cutpoints.add(period[1])
    cutpoints.add(period[2])

ranges = []

start_cutpoint = None
for end_cutpoint in cutpoints:

    if not start_cutpoint:  # skip first
        start_cutpoint = end_cutpoint
        continue

    cut_point_active_periods = []

    for period in periods:

        # check if period and cutpoint range overlap
        start_overlap = max(start_cutpoint, period[1])
        end_overlap = min(end_cutpoint, period[2])

        if start_overlap < end_overlap:
            cut_point_active_periods.append(period[0])

    ranges.append((cut_point_active_periods, start_cutpoint, end_cutpoint))
    start_cutpoint = end_cutpoint
```

Answer (score 1):

Make two records for every interval: `{id, time, start/end}`

Sort list of all these records compared by time. If time fields tie, compare start/end field and choose end first.

Walk through the list.

When you meet start record, add id to `active list`, make time `last time`

When you meet end record, output `active list` with `last time` label to result, then remove id from active list. Change `last time`

let's we have intervals

```
 A: 0..3
 B: 1..2
 C: 2..4
```

Records:

```
 (A,0,s), (A,3,e), (B,1,s), (B,2,e), (C,2,s), (C,4,e)
```

Sorted:

```
 (A,0,s), (B,1,s), (B,2,e), (C,2,s), (A,3,e), (C,4,e)
```

Walk sorted list:

```
  current      active      output         last time
  (A,0,s)      A            -              0           
  (B,1,s)      A,B        A 0..1           1
  (B,2,e)      A          A,B 1..2         2
  (C,2,s)      A,C          -              2
  (A,3,e)      C          A,C  2..3        3
  (C,4,e)      -          C 3..4           4
```

Comment: can you write pseudo code? I don't quite understand your idea.

Answer (score 0):

This was quite a programming challenge for me, but I finally managed to do it. Basically, I sorted all the times along with their ID's, and then I ran a for loop to get the results:

```
from datetime import datetime

timelist = [
    (5, datetime(2010, 9, 19, 0, 0, 0), datetime(2010, 9, 19, 0, 5, 10)),
    (6, datetime(2010, 9, 19, 0, 0, 0), datetime(2010, 9, 19, 12, 59, 59)),
    (4, datetime(2010, 9, 19, 10, 30, 17), datetime(2010, 9, 19, 20, 20, 59)),
    (6, datetime(2010, 9, 19, 14, 12, 0), datetime(2010, 9, 19, 23, 59, 59)),
    (5, datetime(2010, 9, 19, 17, 0, 22), datetime(2010, 9, 19, 19, 14, 20))
]

timelist_new = []
for time in timelist:
    timelist_new.append((time[0], time[1], 'begin'))
    timelist_new.append((time[0], time[2], 'end'))

timelist_new = sorted(timelist_new, key=lambda x: x[1])

key = None
keylist = set()
aggregator = []

for idx in range(len(timelist_new[:-1])):
    t1 = timelist_new[idx]
    t2 = timelist_new[idx + 1]
    t1_key = str(t1[0])
    t2_key = str(t2[0])
    t1_dt = t1[1]
    t2_dt = t2[1]
    t1_pointer = t1[2]
    t2_pointer = t2[2]

    if t1_dt == t2_dt:
        keylist.add(t1_key)
        keylist.add(t2_key)
    elif t1_dt < t2_dt:
        if t1_pointer == 'begin':
            keylist.add(t1_key)
        if t1_pointer == 'end':
            keylist.discard(t1_key)

    key = ','.join(sorted(keylist))
    aggregator.append((key, t1_dt, t2_dt))


for stuff in aggregator:
    print stuff
```

Output:

```
('5,6', datetime.datetime(2010, 9, 19, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2010, 9, 19, 0, 0))
('5,6', datetime.datetime(2010, 9, 19, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2010, 9, 19, 0, 5, 10))
('6', datetime.datetime(2010, 9, 19, 0, 5, 10), datetime.datetime(2010, 9, 19, 10, 30, 17))
('4,6', datetime.datetime(2010, 9, 19, 10, 30, 17), datetime.datetime(2010, 9, 19, 12, 59, 59))
('4', datetime.datetime(2010, 9, 19, 12, 59, 59), datetime.datetime(2010, 9, 19, 14, 12))
('4,6', datetime.datetime(2010, 9, 19, 14, 12), datetime.datetime(2010, 9, 19, 17, 0, 22))
('4,5,6', datetime.datetime(2010, 9, 19, 17, 0, 22), datetime.datetime(2010, 9, 19, 19, 14, 20))
('4,6', datetime.datetime(2010, 9, 19, 19, 14, 20), datetime.datetime(2010, 9, 19, 20, 20, 59))
('6', datetime.datetime(2010, 9, 19, 20, 20, 59), datetime.datetime(2010, 9, 19, 23, 59, 59))

***Repl Closed***
```

Just remove that first line of the output since the begin and end dates are the same :)

```
final_list = []
for stuff in aggregator:
    if stuff[1] != stuff[2]:
        final_list.append(stuff)
```