# Pandas Joining two dataframes on Start and End times that are not equal

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two data frames that each have information about events with Start and End times. The problem is these two data frames have different start and end times because they are measuring different things. Wheat I want to do is create new events that have information for both in them. These would have to be split based on any split between the two data frames. For instance:

Dataframe A:

```
Start                End
2016-12-30 18:51:00  2016-12-30 19:37:00
2016-12-30 20:03:00  2016-12-30 20:11:00
2016-12-30 20:12:00  2016-12-30 21:02:00
2016-12-30 21:02:00  2016-12-30 21:04:00
2016-12-30 21:10:00  2016-12-30 21:12:00
2016-12-30 21:12:00  2016-12-30 21:32:00
```

Dataframe B:

```
Start                End
2016-12-30 18:33:45  2016-12-30 19:18:00
2016-12-30 19:18:00  2016-12-30 19:38:00
2016-12-30 19:38:00  2016-12-30 19:48:00
2016-12-30 19:48:00  2016-12-30 20:15:45
2016-12-30 20:15:45  2016-12-30 20:35:45
2016-12-30 20:35:45  2016-12-30 20:45:45
2016-12-30 20:45:45  2016-12-30 21:14:30
2016-12-30 21:14:30  2016-12-30 21:35:00
```

For these the ideal output would be:

```
Start                End
2016-12-30 18:51:00  2016-12-30 19:18:00
2016-12-30 19:18:00  2016-12-30 19:37:00
2016-12-30 20:03:00  2016-12-30 20:11:00
2016-12-30 20:12:00  2016-12-30 20:15:45
2016-12-30 20:15:45  2016-12-30 20:35:45
2016-12-30 20:35:45  2016-12-30 20:45:45
2016-12-30 20:45:45  2016-12-30 21:12:00
2016-12-30 21:12:00  2016-12-30 21:14:30
2016-12-30 21:14:30  2016-12-30 21:32:00
```

There are a couple of ways I know how to do this. I could explode the dataframes into minute level and merge on like minutes but the issue with this is that each dataframe is 2 million+ rows and it would be a very long process.

I also have SQL that can do this but when I tried to run it it took way too long and the DBA killed the process.

What the SQL does is:

```
select 
a.UNIQUE_ID,
a,
b,
c,
d,
CASE WHEN B.START < A.START THEN A.START
ELSE  B.START END START,
CASE WHEN B.END > A.END THEN A.END
ELSE  B.END END END
from
(Select 
UNIQUE_ID,
START,
END,
a,
b,    
from table_1
)a
    join 
(
UNIQUE_ID,
Select 
START,
END,
c,
d    
from table_2) b
on 1=1
AND A.UNIQUE_ID = B.UNIQUE_ID
AND ((b.START between a.START and a.END)
or (b.end between a.START and a.END)
or (b.START < a.START and b.end > a.end)
or (a.START < b.START and a.end > b.end)
)
) a
```

This makes a row for each pairwise combination of start, end times that contain at least one identical minute for that unique_id. It then uses a case statement to cut back each row to just the shared minutes.

I can't think of an efficient way to replicate this SQL in python using Pandas. The only merge functions that I know in pandas have to have identical columns to merge, they can't be ranges like the join that I use.

Is there a type of merge in pandas I can use to do something similar to:

```
AND ((b.START between a.START and a.END)
or (b.end between a.START and a.END)
or (b.START < a.START and b.end > a.end)
or (a.START < b.START and a.end > b.end)
)
```

The only alternative I can think of is to loop through each row in df A slice back the other dataframe to only rows with minutes in that row of DF b and then merge on those two slices and concatenate all of those merges together into a new DF but that would take  a long time.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So I found a  work around that seems to be working, I'd still ove to hear anyones answers on a good way to do this in pandas, however. 

What I'm doing is using the package pandasql to create a sqlite DB out of the DFs and perform the SQL I know works. It's a pretty nifty package.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to use an implementation that I had written for a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40486375/timeranges-overlapping-algorithm-in-python/40493684#40493684) that was asked similar to what you have:

```
import pandas as pd

df_a = pd.DataFrame({'Start': ['2016-12-30 18:51:00',
                               '2016-12-30 20:03:00',
                               '2016-12-30 20:12:00',
                               '2016-12-30 21:02:00',
                               '2016-12-30 21:10:00',
                               '2016-12-30 21:12:00'],
                     'End': ['2016-12-30 19:37:00',
                             '2016-12-30 20:11:00',
                             '2016-12-30 21:02:00',
                             '2016-12-30 21:04:00',
                             '2016-12-30 21:12:00',
                             '2016-12-30 21:32:00']})
df_b = pd.DataFrame({'Start': ['2016-12-30 18:33:45',
                               '2016-12-30 19:18:00',
                               '2016-12-30 19:38:00',
                               '2016-12-30 19:48:00',
                               '2016-12-30 20:15:45',
                               '2016-12-30 20:35:45',
                               '2016-12-30 20:45:45',
                               '2016-12-30 21:14:30'],
                     'End': ['2016-12-30 19:18:00',
                             '2016-12-30 19:38:00',
                             '2016-12-30 19:48:00',
                             '2016-12-30 20:15:45',
                             '2016-12-30 20:35:45',
                             '2016-12-30 20:45:45',
                             '2016-12-30 21:14:30',
                             '2016-12-30 21:35:00']})

# Convert the strings to datetime
df_a['Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df_a['Start'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df_a['End'] = pd.to_datetime(df_a['End'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df_b['Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df_b['Start'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df_b['End'] = pd.to_datetime(df_b['End'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

# Create labels for the two datasets
# These labels will help determine the overlaps downstream
df_a['Label'] = 'a'
df_b['Label'] = 'b'

# With the labels created, I can concatenate the dataframes now
df_concat = pd.concat([df_a, df_b])
df_concat = df_concat[['Label', 'Start', 'End']]  # Ordering the columns

# Convert the dataframe to a list of tuples
df_concat_rec = df_concat.to_records(index=False)

# Here's where I'm using my answer that I had used in the other question
timelist_new = []
for time in df_concat_rec:
    timelist_new.append((time[0], time[1], 'begin'))
    timelist_new.append((time[0], time[2], 'end'))

timelist_new = sorted(timelist_new, key=lambda x: x[1])

key = None
keylist = set()
aggregator = []

for idx in range(len(timelist_new[:-1])):
    t1 = timelist_new[idx]
    t2 = timelist_new[idx + 1]
    t1_key = str(t1[0])
    t2_key = str(t2[0])
    t1_dt = t1[1]
    t2_dt = t2[1]
    t1_pointer = t1[2]
    t2_pointer = t2[2]

    if t1_dt == t2_dt:
        keylist.add(t1_key)
        keylist.add(t2_key)
    elif t1_dt < t2_dt:
        if t1_pointer == 'begin':
            keylist.add(t1_key)
        if t1_pointer == 'end':
            keylist.discard(t1_key)

    key = ','.join(sorted(keylist))
    aggregator.append((key, t1_dt, t2_dt))

# This is where I filter out any records where there isn't an overlap and where the start and end dates are equal
filtered = [x for x in aggregator if ((len(x[0]) > 1) & (x[1] != x[2]))]

# Convert the list of tuples back to dataframe
final_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(filtered, columns=['Label', 'Start', 'End'])

# Print final dataframe
print(final_df)
```

**Output:**

```
   Label               Start                 End
0    a,b 2016-12-30 18:51:00 2016-12-30 19:18:00
1    a,b 2016-12-30 19:18:00 2016-12-30 19:37:00
2    a,b 2016-12-30 20:03:00 2016-12-30 20:11:00
3    a,b 2016-12-30 20:12:00 2016-12-30 20:15:45
4    a,b 2016-12-30 20:15:45 2016-12-30 20:35:45
5    a,b 2016-12-30 20:35:45 2016-12-30 20:45:45
6    a,b 2016-12-30 20:45:45 2016-12-30 21:02:00
7    a,b 2016-12-30 21:02:00 2016-12-30 21:04:00
8    a,b 2016-12-30 21:10:00 2016-12-30 21:12:00
9    a,b 2016-12-30 21:12:00 2016-12-30 21:14:30
10   a,b 2016-12-30 21:14:30 2016-12-30 21:32:00
```